# How to use system command in a perl script with sudo?

Tags: sudo, tor, perl, kill, killall

I would like to use this in my perl script:

```
sudo killall -HUP tor
```

would this work?:

```
system echo sudo killall -HUP tor
```

Also how would I get around having to authenticate when running the script/from within the script?

Comment: You're solving the wrong problem. See Perl's `kill` function (`perldoc -f kill`, `man perlipc`).

Comment: @waltinator Are you interested in posting an answer about that? As [felwithe has also mentioned](https://askubuntu.com/a/1028858/22949), I think what you've suggested here is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You could, although your syntax is wrong. The correct syntax would simply to use sudo with any of Perl execution methods:

```
system "sudo command";
`sudo command`;
exec "sudo command";
```

But like the comments above point out, it's probably not what you want to do to solve the problem you're trying to solve.